# Como calcular o valor médio dos pixels de rasters em uma lista no R

Tags: lista, r

Eu tentei o códio abaixo, mas na geração do "data frame" só obtenho a média do primeiro raster da lista. Eu preciso de um "data frame" com uma média por raster, cada um numa linha (como na imagem). Eu também preciso remover células com "no data value" do cálculo. Como posso remover esses problemas?

```
rasterlist <- list.files(path="X:/RDirectory/Colabs/Rasters", 
                         pattern =".tif$", full.names=TRUE) #create list of raster file paths

outlist <- list() #create empty list to store outputs from loop

for (i in 1:length(rasterlist)) { #for each raster in rasterlist
  r <- raster(rasterlist[[i]]) #read element i of rasterlist into R
  val <- getValues(r) #get raster values
  m <- mean(val, na.rm=T) #remove NAs and compute mean
  outlist[[i]] <- c(rasterlist[[i]],m) #store raster path with mean
  return("complete")
}

df <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, outlist)) #convert list to data frame
colnames(df) <- c("raster path","mean")
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Po7RT.png

Comment: Veja [Como criar um exemplo mínimo reproduzível em R](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/824/137387)

Comment: Remova a linha `return` do ciclo `for`. Assim que é executada logo na primeira iteração o ciclo acaba. Basta ver o que é que essa função faz.

Answer (score -1):

Como apontado nos comentários, está usando `return` fora de contexto: ela é usada em funções para avaliar uma expressão e encerrar a execução. Se quer exibir uma mensagem, use `cat`. Veja a diferença:

```
for (i in 1:3) {
  print(i)
  return("complete")
}
#> [1] 1

for (i in 1:3) {
  print(i)
  cat("complete\n") # \n representa quebra de linha
}
#> [1] 1
#> complete
#> [1] 2
#> complete
#> [1] 3
#> complete
```

Outras observações sobre seu código: 1) `list.files` retorna um vetor, pode usá-lo diretamente para criar o data.frame; 2) Pode usar `*apply` ao invés de *loop* (mais eficiente):

```
library(raster)

# Arquivos de exemplo
for (i in 1:3) {
  tiff(paste0("plot", i, ".tiff"))
  plot(i:10)
  dev.off()
}

df <- data.frame(name = list.files(pattern ="tiff$"))

df$mean <- sapply(df$name,
  function(x) {
    r <- raster(x)
    val <- getValues(r)
    mean(val, na.rm = TRUE)
  }
)

df
#>         name     mean
#> 1 plot1.tiff 252.9753
#> 2 plot2.tiff 253.0223
#> 3 plot3.tiff 252.8395
```